# Sinon - ensure object does not have property

Tags: sinon

Is there a way with Sinon to have a negative match? Specifically that an object does not have a given property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't currently a built-in matcher for that.

`Sinon` allows you to create [custom matchers](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.2/matchers/#custom-matchers) so you could create your own, here is one for `doesNotHave` based on [the built-in `has` matcher](https://github.com/sinonjs/samsam/blob/02f7329f9b309de8fd732a6184005d3a4c126f90/lib/matcher.js#L266-L271):

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

const doesNotHave = (prop) => sinon.match(function (actual) {
  if(typeof value === "object") {
    return !(prop in actual);
  }
  return actual[prop] === undefined;
}, "doesNotHave");

test('properties', () => {
  const obj = { foo: 'bar' };
  sinon.assert.match(obj, sinon.match.has('foo'));  // SUCCESS
  sinon.assert.match(obj, doesNotHave('baz'));  // SUCCESS
})
```

Comment: It should be `typeof actual` instead of `typeof value`. In any case, this is a good custom matcher example

Answer (score 3):

I've just realized that it's possible to specify `undefined` in the object's shape to make the check:

```js
sinon.assert.match(actual, {
  shouldNotExists: undefined
});
```

Not completely sure if it's 100% valid, but seems to do the job.

Comment: In my testing, this only evaluates to true if the object has the property

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `sinon` for this, you have to use something like `chai`.

You would do:

```
cont { expect } = require("chai");

expect({ foo: true }).to.not.have.keys(['bar']);
```

https://runkit.com/embed/w9qwrw2ltmpz